# =TEXT formula not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to use the formula =text(F4,"MMM") and it works for some fields as it displays the month, but for other fields it's not working, simply displays as "27/05/2016" . Any idea as to why might that be? I checked the formatting and nothing seems to be wrong with that.

Thanks

Comment: have you checked if the cells where its not working are formatted as date?

Comment: Yes. So at the beginning I had it formatted as "General", but I even changed to "Short Date", but still doesn't seem to work. In any ways all formats are constant but only works for some of them

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot with show formula turned on, where cells are shown that are working and some that are not?

Comment: Sure, https://postimg.org/image/l8ik5avg7/

Comment: Almost, but you should turn on "Show Formula" its a button on the formula tab. After its on, you don't see the result of the formulas, rathen than the formula itself in each cell.

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/3wjf86pgh/ what about this one?

Comment: As you can see the cells that are not working are the ones that the date is larger than 12. your date format is dd/mm/yyyy (see row 10). looks like excel understands it only in mm/dd/yyy. but this still does not explane why when its on General it doesn't work

Comment: That seems to be the issue thanks. How would I change that now? I press Ctrl+1 and under "Date" I change format but it doesn't seem to change. When I manually change the date,  it seems to work...

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: [This](http://superuser.com/questions/564321/converting-dates-stored-as-text-to-proper-date-format-i-e-dd-mm-yyyy) might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your dateformat is month/day/year. Thats way it works for the dates, where the day, i.e. the middle part, is smaller than 12. Try to change it for one date, and see if it fits.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. Turns out the format was mm/dd/yyyy and the formula was getting messed up. So to change the whole row of data into another format dd/mm/yyyy do the following:

Data > Text to columns > Next > Next > under "column data format" choose "Date" > in dropdown select MDY > OK

Should work after :)

Answer (score 0):

Excel cannot read your European formatted dates.  It is storing them as text instead of as dates.  This is why changing nothing happens when you change the date format.

Assuming all of the problem dates you have are formatted with two digit days and months and four digit years (DD/MM/YYYY), use this formula to convert to a US date:

```
=DATE(VALUE(RIGHT(F4,4)), VALUE(MID(F4,4,2)), VALUE(LEFT(F4,2)))
```

This uses the RIGHT, MID and LEFT functions to get the day, month and year and then turns it into a proper date value using the DATE function.

If some dates have one digit months or years, or 2 digit years, use this much longer formula.  It splits the date into three pieces by finding the forward slashes.

```
=DATE( MID( F4, FIND( "/", F4, FIND( "/", F4 ) + 1 ) + 1, 4 ), MID(F4, FIND( "/", F4 ) + 1, FIND( "/", F4, FIND( "/", F4 ) + 1 ) - FIND( "/", F4 ) - 1 ), LEFT( F4, FIND( "/", F4 ) - 1 ) )
```

Comment: The answer from Nika Dolidze on using the Text to Columns feature is also a great solution!

Answer (score 0):

The month function is not working properly on excel, you will need to convert date to a Julian one in order to accomplish your task.
The EDATE formula will help you to convert your date from F4 cell into Julian

Example i used:

TEXT(EDATE(F4,0),"MMM")